# Specific merge 2 columns in sql excluding one of them

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have table like this:

```
| user1 | user2 |
|   1   |   2   |
|   3   |   1   |
|   4   |   1   |
|   1   |   5   |
|  ...  |  ...  |
```

I wanna merge this columns into one, but in new merged column must be number, which not equals with one given. That is if I used this query on table above and give number 1:

```
SELECT CONCAT(user1, user2) AS user FROM table WHERE user1 = 1 or user2 = 1
```

I have returned this:

```
| user |
|  12  |
|  31  |
|  41  |
|  15  |
|  ..  |
```

When it should return this:

```
| user  |
|   2   |
|   3   |
|   4   |
|   5   |
|  ...  |
```

1 is an example. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(user1 = 1, user2, user1) AS user
FROM table
WHERE user1 = 1 OR user2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user1 AS users FROM `table` WHERE user1 NOT IN (SELECT user2 FROM `table`)
 UNION 
SELECT user2 AS users FROM `table` WHERE user2 NOT IN (SELECT user1 FROM `table`)
ORDER BY users
```